# devExpress winform GridLookUpEdit not selecting newly added value after ProcessNewValue event

Tags: devexpress

hi I am working with devexpress winform controls, specifically GridLookUpEdit, I try to save new records asynchronously, in the GridLookUpEdit_ProcessNewValue event, but I cannot get the created record to be automatically selected, I have tried saving asynchronous without the "await" and it works fine, but I need be able to wait for the result of the operation before adding to the GridLookUpEdit datasource.
Does anyone know why this can happen, or how could this problem be solved?

```
 DevExpress.XtraEditors.GridLookUpEdit gridLookUp = sender as DevExpress.XtraEditors.GridLookUpEdit;
        try
        {
            var pais = cboPais.EditValue?.ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pais))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }

            if ((string)e.DisplayValue != String.Empty && FrameUtil.MostrarMensage(
                        this, "Confirmar", "Desea crear un registro nuevo ?", "La provincia o estado  '" + e.DisplayValue.ToString() + "' aun no se a agregado al pais " +
                        pais + Environment.NewLine + "Presione si para continuar y agregarlo",
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                ProvinciaDto provincia = new ProvinciaDto()
                {
                    CodigoPais = pais,
                    Descripcion = e.DisplayValue.ToString()
                };

                await _context.Provincias.GuardarAsync(provincia);

                ListaGenerica<ProvinciaDto> listaProvincias = bsProvincia.DataSource as ListaGenerica<ProvinciaDto>;
                listaProvincias.Add(provincia);

                e.DisplayValue = provincia.Descripcion;
                gridLookUp.Refresh();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FrameUtil.MostrarMensageError(this, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried this by removing these lines `e.DisplayValue = provincia.Descripcion;
                gridLookUp.Refresh();`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to refer this - [RepositoryItemLookUpEditBase.ProcessNewValue Event](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEditBase.ProcessNewValue)

It is a simple example to add one record to the data source of the GridLoopEdit. You should try to remove `e.DisplayValue = provincia.Descripcion; gridLookUp.Refresh();`.

```
//ProcessNewValue event handler
void LookUpEdit1_ProcessNewValue(object sender, ProcessNewValueEventArgs e) {
    if ((string)e.DisplayValue != String.Empty && MessageBox.Show(
        this, "Add the '" + e.DisplayValue.ToString() + "' entry to the list?",
        "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes) {
            ContactList list = (sender as LookUpEdit).Properties.DataSource as ContactList;
            list.Add(new Contact(list.Count, e.DisplayValue.ToString()));
            e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. I had a health problem, so now I resume my activities.
your solution is the example provided by dev express, if before adding to the list, you execute an await saveAsync (contact) it doesn't work, the same happens with all dev express editors, that's why I was asking, and I can't find a solution ...